# How do I run and compile this github project on my pc?

Tags: github, github-for-windows

This project https://github.com/DesktopUpload/DesktopUploader has been uploaded on gitHub.

How can I compile the source code of this project and transform it into an .exe application where I run it on my PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop,http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs. Open the project (the .cbproj file) and build it and there will be an .exe in the build folder.

Comment: Visual Studio does not run .cbproj file.